# How do I write queries that target more than one possible criteria without writing multiple queries in ASP.NET Webforms?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, url-routing

I have [followed this tutorial on URL Routing for ASP.NET 4.5 WebForms](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/url-routing) by By Erik Reitan, and the advantages of URL Routing are made clear in that post.

One drawback I'm seeing is having to write new queries for each way I want to query the database by.

For example, to implement a search by Product ID, I have to do the following:

Using standard mechanism a link is:

```
<a href="ProductDetail.aspx?productID=<%#:Item.ProductID%>">
```

---

### Implementing URL Routing

1. Register the Routes at application startup

   ```
   void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
       {
           routes.MapPageRoute(
               "ProductByNameRoute",
               "Product/{productName}",
               "~/ProductDetails.aspx"
           );
       }
   ```
2. Modify the ProductList.aspx markup:

   ```
    <a href="<%#: GetRouteUrl("ProductByNameRoute", new {productName = Item.ProductName}) %>"
      <%#:Item.ProductName%>
    </a>
   ```
3. Modify the code-behind (ProductList.aspx.cs):

   ```
   public IQueryable<Product> GetProduct(
                       [QueryString("ProductID")] int? productId,
                       [RouteData] string productName)
       {
           var _db = new WingtipToys.Models.ProductContext();
           IQueryable<Product> query = _db.Products;
           if (productId.HasValue && productId > 0)
           {
               query = query.Where(p => p.ProductID == productId);
           }
           else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(productName))
           {
               query = query.Where(p =>
                         String.Compare(p.ProductName, productName) == 0);
           }
           else
           {
               query = null;
           }
           return query;
       }
   ```

If I want to query by `ProductName`, I now have to write a new query.

How can I get around the issue of having to write new queries for each way that I want to query a product by?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really meant for a 'pros/cons' discussion in the form of 'any insights appreciated'.  Those incite discussion, which doesn't scale well on Stack Overflow. I've also made your question less open ended so that it won't be so broad (advantages/disadvantages is a broad question with many possible 'correct' answers).

Comment: Thank you very much for your re-formatting! Essentially that is the problem in a nutshell ;-)